# #g-recaptcha-response dont load in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, puppeteer

so ma using puppeteer and axios for automation purpose, am getting the Add to card cookies using axios then send them as an header in puppeteer in this way await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({})
when the checkout page load i cant click the button that trigger the captcha i saw the inspect and it turned up that it's not even there
i inspect a full browser automation mode and it was there so I don't think it's a anti-bot problem  and it's there, only when i use that way it just disappear

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM99F.png)

This is my header

```
  await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
    //  "Host": "www.supremenewyork.com",
  "Connection": "keep-alive",
  "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
  "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36",
  'Accept':"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
  "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
  "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
  "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "Sec-Fetch-User": "1",
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
  "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
  "referer" :`https://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile/`,
  "Accept-Encoding": " gzip, deflate, br",
  "Accept-Language": " en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
  "Cookie": `${set_cookie}`,
  // "dnt": "1",
  // "sec-fetch-site" : "same-origin"
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this header I deleted the headers that may be blocking  the loading of the captcha

```
  await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
  "Connection": "keep-alive",
   "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36",
'Accept':"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
  "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
  "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
  "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "Sec-Fetch-User": "1",
  "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
  "referer" :`https://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile/`,
  "Accept-Encoding": " gzip, deflate, br",
  "Accept-Language": " en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
  "Cookie": `${set_cookie}`,
  "dnt": "1",
  "sec-fetch-site" : "same-origin"
},
)
```